# Safari mute tab while it isn't playing audio

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

In Safari 14 on macOS Big Sur 11.2.1, How can I mute the current tab in Safari when it isn't playing audio right now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

Even if you add a key command, it simply doesn't respond & stays greyed-out unless there is actually audio playing. It doesn't even highlight if video is playing, if it has no sound.